# Add element to map of maps dynamically Java 8

Tags: java

This should be easy to find similar question on the net, but i couldn't.
I want to add dynamically elements to Map that contains other Maps etc

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>>
```

the thing is i want something neat , short and elegant, ideally like in Java 9

```
Map<"test",Map.of("test1","Test2")>
```

but i am stuck to Java 8 in this project , so i tried with Guava.

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> kon;
kon.put("yuo",ImmutableMap.of(" Masdad","dada"));
```

but it complains kon is not initializes, any suggestions ?

Comment: "ideally like in Java 9" That snippet is not valid in Java 9, or indeed any version of Java past, present, or future.

Comment: You should probably read up on how java works, like the *1. tutorial*. You need to initialize local variables before you use them. E.g: `kon = new HashMap<>()` in your example

Comment: @user2557930 Java is **very** verbose, so you can't really achieve this directly. You may want to use Kotlin which allows something like this `map[key] = value`

Comment: ok ,Thanks Lino !

Answer (score 2):

> but it complains kon is not initializes, any suggestions ?

Initialize your Map.

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> kon = new HashMap<>();
kon.put("yuo",ImmutableMap.of(" Masdad","dada"));
```

Comment: Uncle Bob says initializing variables is a code smell

Answer (score 2):

It complains "kon is not initialized" because you have not initialized it.

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> kon = new HashMap<>();
```